# upper bound for $\frac{x+y}{ax+y}$

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus

I need an upper bound for 
$$\frac{x+y}{ax+y}$$

I know that $$1\leq a< 2$$ 
$x\geq 0 $ and $y\geq 0 $ . This upper bound can include just $a$ and constant numbers not $x$ or $y$.

thanks a lot.

Answer (score 3):

Hint: If $x=0$, then $\frac{x+y}{ax+y}=1$. Suppose $x\neq0$. Let $t=\frac{y}{x}$. Then $\frac{x+y}{ax+y}=\frac{t+1}{a+t}=1-\frac{a-1}{a+t}$.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:**

$\dfrac{x+y}{ax+y}=\dfrac{ax+y-(a-1)x}{ax+y}=1-\dfrac{(a-1)x}{ax+y}$

What's the minimum value of $\dfrac{(a-1)x}{ax+y}$?

Since $x,y \ge 0$ and $a \ge 1$, minimum value of the $\dfrac{(a-1)x}{ax+y}$ is $0$.

Answer (score 1):

Here is how you advance, since $x,y>0$, then

$$ 1\leq a < 2\implies  x\leq ax < 2x \implies x+y\leq ax+y < 2x+y   $$

$$ \implies \frac{1}{2x+y}<\frac{1}{ax+y}\leq \frac{1}{x+y} \implies \frac{x+y}{ax+y}\leq \frac{x+y}{x+y}=1 $$

$$ \implies \frac{x+y}{ax+y}\leq 1. $$